# updating url rewriting rule with vs2012 web deployment web.config transformations

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

I can't figure out how to get my web.config deployment transformation to work for a rewrite rule.  I've tried the following and it ignores it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">


 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <rules>

    <rule name="Force HTTPS On Login/Register" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="Account/Login(.*)|Register(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>


    <rule name="Force HTTPS Off" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="((Account/Login(.*))|(Register(.*)))" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>


  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: worked as you suggested.  so far I have not had to use slowcheetah. I keep hearing about it but just hate to keep adding to my dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use SlowCheetah to transform my web.config for production.  I originally tried what you tried, but found that I had to add an empty

```
<rewrite>
  <rules />
</rewrite>
```

to the base web.config

and then write a transform like

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="Insert">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

(that is a redirect transform, but I think the same principal should apply).

Note `xdt:Transform="Insert"` to insert a new node into the skeletal `<rules />` in the base config file.

Comment: Hi Eric, Have you ever seen a problem where the empty <rewrite> rule gives an http 500.19 error? My azure VM throws that error, but my colo server (same OS) does not.

Comment: No I have not seen that situation, though I'm not using Azure.  Perhaps post a new question about that error specific to Azure?  That error means that the config file is invalid.  Are you sure that the transform was correctly applied to the Azure VM?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx